# R Find date closest (before) a specified date column

Tags: r

I am trying to return the index number of a column with the date closest (but prior) to a specific date column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
TimeK <- c("12/31/2017", "12/13/2017",  "12/01/2017", "12/01/2017", 
"12/05/2017")
Time1 <- c("01/01/2018",  "12/03/2017", "11/17/2018", "11/01/2017", 
"12/05/2017")
Time2 <- c("12/28/2017", "12/13/2017", "12/01/2017", "10/01/2017", 
"09/12/2017")
Time3 <- c("01/08/2018", "12/01/2017", "11/23/2017", "06/01/2017", "12/31/2017")

d <- data.frame(TimeK,Time1,Time2,Time3) %>% mutate_all(funs(mdy)) 


closest <- function(g) {(which.min(interval(g,d$Timek)<0))}

d$closest_date <- apply(d[,-c(1)], MARGIN = 1, FUN= closest)
```

In this case I want column index of the date in each row of Time1:Time3 that is closest to (but prior) to Time K.  The goal output of the new variable would be (2,1,3,1,2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a dplyr solution:

```
d  = d%>% mutate(rowid=1:n());
d1 = d %>% gather(TimeID,value,-c(rowid,TimeK)) %>% mutate(DateDiff = as.integer(TimeK-value))
d2 = d1 %>% group_by(rowid) %>% filter(DateDiff > 0);

# TimeID 
d2 %>% group_by(rowid) %>% arrange(DateDiff) %>% filter(1:n() == 1) %>% arrange(rowid) %>% select(TimeID)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for( i  in c(2:4)) {
   print(which.min(ifelse( (d[,1] - d[,i]) > 0 , (d[,1] - d[,i]),999999)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this code can help you
I dont quite get what you mentioned with the goal output (2,1,3,1,2) though

```
difftime(d[2,1],d[2,3], units="days")
#Time difference of 0 days
```